# How do I add more items to this type of name value pair array?

Tags: swift

my array is like this:

```
let params :[String : AnyObject]? = ["name":self.name!, "surname":self.surname!]
```

I want to add more items but append wont work. How do I do that?

The error I get when I try append:

```
Value of type '[String: AnyObject]?' has no member 'append'
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplication [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841106/extra-argument-in-call-with-swift-2/36841232#36841232)

Comment: I get this error when I try using append: Value of type '[String: AnyObject]?' has no member 'append'

Comment: It's not an array, it's a dictionary. Even more, it's an Optional Dictionary.

Comment: Can I have multiple values for same keys? For example I need both "ShareTo": "person1" and "ShareTo": "person2"

Comment: you need to change `let` to `var`. If you declare `params` as a constant the dictionary will be immutable.